# ActiveRecord Error: Couldn't find User without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, rails-activerecord

I've been building a web app that allows users to sign in with Facebook and then redirect to their profile feed. If the user does not exist, a new record will be created with their Facebook credentials and stored in the Users model.

The problem that I am having is that when I try to redirect back from the Facebook callback to the user's profile page, their record cannot be found (I get the error **ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show**), regardless of whether or not the record existed already or has been newly created in the process of signing in.

I am using OmniAuth for authentication and access to the Facebook Graph API, loosely following the conventions outlined in Ryan Bates RailsCast #360 (http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication?autoplay=true)

### Here is my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)  
    where(auth.slice(:uid)).first_or_create.tap do |user|
       user.uid = auth.uid
       user.name = auth.info.name
       user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
       user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
       user.img_url = auth.info.image
       user.save!
    end
  end
end
```

as well as the two associated controllers,

### SessionsController:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    redirect_to '/auth/facebook'
  end

  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to user
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

### and UsersController:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:uid])
  end
end
```

## Trace Data and Session Dump

Additionally, the the trace shows that the error is occurs in the 'show' method of the Users controller:

```
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:4:in `show'
```

What I don't understand is why the query to show the user uses an id field which is not part of the model, as shown in the Request Parameters:

```
{"id"=>"1"}
```

and the Session dump:

```
_csrf_token: "sjym9SfVWrLipH/7Lxn4RCp2Df6kQTNITnhjro2tirI="
session_id: "7d2c6e70bcae6f1ec257fd634a73c44b"
user_id: 1
```

Most perplexing is that when I use the rails console to examine the Users database, the following hash is returned with an additional ID field included that was not part of the original schema:

```
=> #<User id: 1, uid: "1123581321", name: "Bob Loblaw", oauth_token: "AAAHFZAqhAyeEBADdZCxeCIdFQWjkbQFjfGfJjCiZA8VKSAw5zy...", oauth_expires_at: "2013-04-14 01:15:20", created_at: "2013-02-13 01:19:24", updated_at: "2013-02-13 01:57:18", img_url: "http://graph.facebook.com/1123581321/picture?type=s...">
```

### Schema:

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "uid"
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "oauth_token"
  t.datetime "oauth_expires_at"
  t.datetime "created_at",       :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",       :null => false
  t.string   "img_url"
end
```

### Routes

The routes are fairly standard, I don't believe that the problem lies there:

```
resources :users

root to: 'static_pages#home'

match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
match 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
match 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'

match '/how_it_works',    to: 'static_pages#how_it_works'
match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
```

Comment: Just a note: you do not want to store uid in your `User` without also storing provider name. uid is created by the provider and could possibly clash with another provider's uid.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @mcl, since I'm only implementing this with Facebook authentication I chose to exclude the provider for the timebeing. If I decide to add other providers, I will obviously have to do as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because rails is looking for the user_id saved in your database to access the record. so you need to have it as

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

when you are showing a specific user. rails needs to find the user_id. That is why you are getting that error.

if you look at your sessions create method it is creating via sessions[:id] = user.id

the user_id column is automatically created when you create a table.